# Using Arduino + MOSFET to automate the pressing of button

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I am working on using Arduino Uno to automate the pressing of buttons. The configuration to the left is the current configuration and it works fine. However, the configuration to the right doesn't. Could someone help with this matter?

P.S. I've tried using relays and it works, but I don't want to use them because they are too big.

[P36N06 Datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/3142.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Have you done the math yet?

Comment: Reed relays can be pretty small, [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/CRR05-1A/374-1039-1-ND/698050) is 8.6 x 4.4 mm.

Comment: Use a PFET on high side.. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67343/mosfet-as-a-switch  with a NFET driving gate of the PFET low whenever Encoder Pin needs to be driven to 12 V

Comment: Do you know what the encoder chip is? Could you potentially use a pullup, with a FET to pull it low when on?

Comment: Datasheet of the encoder chip would be nice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Umar's solution. It works.. To Ignacio: I should have pay more attention at school when learning how to do circuit analysis. Now I know where such skill could be used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOT packages can save cost. But if there are multiple pins to be controlled individually, number of FETs required will be 2*No. of encoder pins

[image]
Source: [MOSFET as a switch?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67343/mosfet-as-a-switch)